# Create Clickable, Reusable NFL Field Component in React and CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, responsive-design, react-bootstrap

I've created an NFL field using css. I am trying to implement a clicking interface in React where the user is able to mouse-click any area on the pitch, which then retrieves the specific yard of that position.

[CodeSandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-euclid-sur06?file=/src/App.js)

I am facing a few problems:

1. I don't know how to make this field responsive, in order for it to become a reusable component. Ideally, I would like to use the `react-bootstrap` framework to place this field within columns and rows, but I'm not sure how to adjust the css as such for this to work.
2. I am using the MouseEvents `clientX` and `clientY` to pinpoint the exact coordinates on the pitch, so I can map them to the yards. On my laptop screen I have been able to do this in the `mapYardCoordinates` function. However, any change of resolution or device will result in these x and y values becoming inaccurate. How can I overcome this issue?